# Auto import does not work in Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter

[image: Auto import not working]

auto import does not working imported it that is with any package installed and any files in project in android studio

[image: this is flutter doctor]

Comment: I loved you theme, can you please share it...

Answer (score 6):

This is often happened to me as well.
What do I do usually are :

- close the project via `File -> Close Project`
- open file explorer (finder/explorer)
- go to the project location, show hidden files,
- Then delete the `.idea` folder
- open the project again via Android Studio
- finally everything works normal again

Comment: i did not find ant folder .idea in any project files

Comment: aha okay sure about delete this folder and the project re run again it is not hidden

Comment: @MohamedAlsiny You have to list the content in the shell using ls -al

Comment: can you explan more

Answer (score 3):

May be the problem is with Android Studio Indexing...

Follow the steps..

Go to 'File' > 'Invalidate caches/restart'

Now the studio will shut down and restart. Now indexing begins. On completion of indexing you will find the Suggestion boxes with every possible suggestions.

If it didn't work try this..

Go to File > Settings > Editor > General > Auto Import > Dart and Select auto import to yes...

Answer (score 0):

Restarting my dart analysis after flutter pub get works for me.

[image: First button]

Comment: I try that but still not working